# Get all terms if product of that term contains a specific category

Tags: tags, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using below code for get all product tags:

```
$tags = get_terms('product_tag', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=1');
```

However, I want to show only those tags in which product having these tags but must contain a specific product category like `shop`.

Mean if a `product1` contains `tag1` and shop category 
`product2` contains `tag2` and any other category, then only `tag1` will show.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar. This is what I did:

```
$args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => get_query_var('taxonomy'),
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => get_query_var('term'),
            )
        ),
    );
    $products = new WP_Query($args);
    $attributes = array();
    while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post();
        $post_atts = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'pa_' . $attr);
        if ($post_atts) {
            foreach ($post_atts as $x) {
                if(!in_array($x, $attributes)){
                    $attributes[]=$x;
                }
            }
        }
    endwhile;
    print_r($attributes1);
```

This code is written for product and attributes, so you'll have to modify it for your need.